# Script for vertical and horizontal scroll bar in Kindo grid in selenium webdriver eclipse

Tags: jquery, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, grid, scrollbar

I need to click on a link in Kindo grid to redirect to respective page, I need to scroll vertically to right to see the link item and click. I uses the following script which is doesn't work

```
JavascriptExecutor scroll = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            scroll.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)","");
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If the driver can find the link item, but just can't see it to click, you should use:

```
JavascriptExecutor scroll (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    scroll.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.find(/*your selector here*/));
```

If you give us an example of your html, I can help you if this isn't enough.